# Changes that web.config in WCF service needed to support Rest

Tags: c#, wcf, rest

I have a WCF service that is working with Soap. I need this working with rest as well. I have added a `WebGet` attribute to my method as follows:

```
[OperationContract]
[WebGet(UriTemplate = "login/{username}/{password}/{PartnerID}")]
Model.PartnerAuthentication authenticate(Model.PartnerRequest request);
```

But when I change some configuration related to rest in config file I am getting error. not sure that my config related to rest is correct:

This is in my `web.config`:

```
<services>
    <service behaviorConfiguration="HubBehavior" name="Acquisition.AcquisitionService">
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
        <endpoint 
            binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="basicBinding"
            contract="Acquisition.IAcquisition" />
        <endpoint name="wsEndpoint" 
            address="ws" 
            binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="wsBinding"
            contract="Acquisition.IAcquisition" />
        <endpoint 
            address="web"  
            behaviorConfiguration="restfulBehavior" 
            binding="webHttpBinding"     
            contract="Acquisition.IAcquisition"/>
    </service>
</services>
```

The last endpoint in related to rest and my Behavior are:

```
<behaviors>
    <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="restfulBehavior">
            <webHttp/>
        </behavior>
    </endpointBehaviors>
    <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="HubBehavior">
            <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
            <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
        </behavior>
    </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample code segment which you can use. here i added sample method which you have to implement in your service class and then I added web config for that WCF service. Hope this will help you to solve
your problem.

```
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "GET",
    ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml,
    BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped,
    UriTemplate = "/GetNameXML?name={name}")]
    string GetNameXML(string name); 


<system.serviceModel>  
   <services>  
    <service name="WcfService1.TestService" behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehaviour">  
     <endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="WcfService1.ITestService" behaviorConfiguration="web">  
     </endpoint>  
    </service>  
   </services>  
   <behaviors>  
    <serviceBehaviors>  
     <behavior name="ServiceBehaviour">  
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>  
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>  
     </behavior>  
    </serviceBehaviors>  
    <endpointBehaviors>  
     <behavior name="web">  
      <webHttp/>  
     </behavior>  
    </endpointBehaviors>  
   </behaviors>  
  </system.serviceModel>
```